# Capture Stereo Mixer Voice

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

By NAudio .net library, I'm trying to capture "Stereo Mixer" voice.

```
var recorder = new WaveIn();
```

This WaveIn class captures from mic. How to change to Stereo mix?

Note: Stereo Mixer is enabled.

Comment: Check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using Windows Vista or newer, NAudio's `WasapiLoopbackCapture` class is the best way to do this.